# Approval Process - too many emails

Tags: approval-process

I'm having an odd issue that I cannot get to the bottom of.

I have the follow object, and approval process setup:

Custom Object

- Custom Fields [...]
- User 1 Field
- User 2 Field

**Approval Step 1:**
Email Alert to Queue for first approval

**Approval Step 2:**
Email Alert to User 1 for Approval

**Approval Step 3:**
Email Alert to User 2 for Approval

Email alerts in Step 2 and 3 are both set to Related User: User 1/2 Field

When the approval process goes to step 2, everyone in the step 1 queque are getting email alerts - when it should only be the users in step 2 to get the email.

Am I missing something somewhere?

Comment: What kind of email alerts are they getting? Is it related to approval?

Comment: Yes, they are getting emails related to the approval.